# References won't add automatically in visual studio 2005

Tags: c#

My problem is the references won't add automatically to my code in visual studio 2005. It works fine in vs 2013. But in 2005, there is no reference to the class that I use this methods. It generates an error says "reallandtest.Entity.DeviceCommEty.Device.set' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern"

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using Riss.Devices;

    namespace reallandtest.Entity 
    {
       public class DeviceCommEty
       {
           public DeviceCommEty() { }

           public DeviceConnection DeviceConnection { get; set; }

           public Device Device { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check that you are still targeting the same .Net version when using VS2005.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. still working on it

Comment: Removed my previous comments 'cause they were wrong, just had some testing and googled it a bit. Posted an answer as a result of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a VS2005 compiler limitation...

"*Automatic properties are a function of the compiler, not of the framework you're targeting. VS2013 will still work with automatic properties when targeting the .Net 2.0 runtime. However VS2005 will not give you automatic properties.*"

Source: https://forums.asp.net/post/3021629.aspx

This code (modified due of the missing classes), targetting in both VS for framework 2.0 raises an error only in VS2005

```
using System;

namespace reallandtest.Entity
{
    public class DeviceCommEty
    {
        public DeviceCommEty() { }

        public DeviceConnection DeviceConnection { get; set; }

        public Device Device { get; set; }

    }

    public class DeviceConnection
    {
    }

    public class Device
    {
    }
}
```

To make it work, you should get rid off the automatic (bodyless) properties.

```
    public class DeviceCommEty
    {
        public DeviceCommEty() { }

        private DeviceConnection _deviceConnection;

        public DeviceConnection DeviceConnection 
        {
            get
            {
                return _deviceConnection; 
            }
            set
            {
               _deviceConnection = value;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.really appreciated. but in above code there is an another error it says " 'DeviceConnection' is an ambiguous reference between 'Riss.Devices.DeviceConnection' and 'reallandtest.Entity.DeviceConnection' ".

Comment: It is the code I used to reproduce your error, it does not fix it... because it cannot be fixed. If you use that code in the project you hace the reference to the `Riss.Devices`namespace/assembly it will give you that error. Please notice the `VS2013 will still work with automatic properties when targeting the .Net 2.0 runtime. However VS2005 will not give you automatic properties.`

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks for the help bradbury9

Answer (score 0):

```
//Finally got it. This worked for me.

namespace reallandtest.Entity 
{

    public class DeviceCommEty
    {
        public DeviceCommEty() { }

        public DeviceConnection deviceConnection
        {
            get { return deviceConnection; }
            set { deviceConnection= value; }
        }

        public Device device
        {
            get { return device; }
            set { device= value; }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This would compile, but at runtime it will give you error. You should declare a private variable and use it.

Comment: You have declared a recursive getter, will raise stack overflow exception.

Comment: Ok I will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: bradbury you were right.there is an error 'System.StackOverflowException' when I try to call this on another class. What should I do now? any help? I'm new to c# and help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check the edit in my answer, last code fragment. It it works for you, mark that answer as helpful/solved.